# MS Office and Adobe Acrobat pdf file thumbnails are not showing correctly

Tags: thumbnails

[image]

As you can see in screenshot above, my .pdf and MS Office files' thumbnails are not showing properly. Tried cleaning thumbnail cache and unchecking related field in folder options in view tab but no luck so far.

Comment: what operating system do you use? When this started to happen? Did you changed anything in  the system? ...

Comment: I would say its more of a corrupted install than thumbnail cache issue